# How to remove google map marker with fade out animation iOS swift 3?

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3

I am trying to remove my google map marker with fade out animation. And I have tried

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
myMarker.marker?.map = nil
CATransaction.commit()
```

`CATransaction` worked for `myMarker.marker?.rotation` but not working for fade out animation. What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there are several markers or some code snippet depend on that marker, and you need to remove them synchronously then the process you should be done in background thread. But the background thread can't update the UI.

So, the UI update portion you need do in main thread. Like I have done here,

```
//Swift 3.1
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    //HERE MAY HAVE SOME DEPENDENT CODE

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.myMarker.marker?.opacity = 0.0
        }, completion: { (yes) in
            self.myMarker.marker?.map = nil
        })
    }

    //HERE MAY HAVE SOME DEPENDENT CODE

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this to hide it with animation, use any method of your choice in *option* parameter:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { 

      self.myMarker.opacity = 0.0

}, completion: { (true) in

      self.myMarker.map = nil              
})
```

Comment: I have tried with this also with my given snippet, but this not animates.

Comment: If you will search you will see CATransaction have a bug that calls completion block immediately and there are some conditions given in doc that let you know why it calls it immediately, Is it possible for you to use UIView animation to fade out marker ? I tried this in a project and marker fades out using UIView animation given in above code.

Comment: Thanks @ NeverHopeless, I didn't know before that CATransaction have bug. I feel UIView animation is a better way than the CATransaction.